# Magnific popup does not close on page redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I have a iframe-based Magnific popup and its content is a form called from another page.

When I submit and redirect in PHP it only reloads the page on Magnific popup, it does not close the popup and does not redirect the main page.

```
<a href="popup.html" class="popup-youtube"></a>
```

```js
$('.popup-youtube').magnificPopup({
  type: 'iframe'
});

$.extend(true, $.magnificPopup.defaults, {  
  iframe: {
    patterns: {
      youtube: {
        index: 'youtube.com/', 
        id: 'v=', 
        src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1' 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: So add `target="_top"` on the `form` element …?

Comment: Wow, great answer, thank you for help, Rory